# Lighthouse performance test "Properly Size images"... are my srcset/sizes wrong?

Tags: html, lighthouse

Image container is 1920px wide **as maximum**. My source image is 1920x600px. I'm try to serve different image for each viewport size:

```html
<img alt="" src="/media/foo.jpeg" class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto"
   sizes="
       (min-width: 1200px) 1200px,
       (min-width: 992px) 992px,
       (min-width: 768px) 768px,
       100vw
   "
   srcset="
       /media/foo_768.jpeg 768w,
       /media/foo_992.jpeg 992w,
       /media/foo_1200.jpeg 1200w,
       /media/foo_1920.jpeg 1920w,
   "
   width="1920" height="600">
```

Attributes `width` and `height` must be present to allow the browser to calculate the reserved space without downloading the image.

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: _"Image container is 1920px wide as maximum"_ - you're aware that the media conditions in `sizes` are related to the viewport though, not any containers, right?

Comment: Seems correct. Also, just a suggestion you can also try using **[`<picture>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture)**